# How to start making a game engine in C#

Tags: game-engine

How would i go about making a game engine from scratch, i know that this is a very hard task and the final engine will not be able to compete with an engine like Unreal or Unity.

I only plan to use this to get better at programming and if it helps i'm using C#.

Comment: http://gamasutra.com/blogs/MichaelKissner/20151027/257369/Writing_a_Game_Engine_from_Scratch__Part_1_Messaging.php

Answer (score 5):

Check: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/06/14/A-tutorial-series-on-building-a-game-engine-from-scratch-almost-literally.aspx

You may also want to check more interactive tutorials such as those on 
 [Udemy](http://Udemy.com), which cost some money but offer a much more interactive environment. I'm sure you will be able to find a C# game engine guide on there.